# Jackson can't parse json, returns NPE

Tags: java, json, parsing, jackson

I'm trying to parse json (steam webchat) which looks like that (I've changed response cause I don't wanna show the data):

```
/**/({
"pollid": 00,
"messages": [
    {
        "type": "personastate",
        "timestamp": 0000000000,
        "utc_timestamp": 000000000,
        "steamid_from": "000000000000",
        "status_flags": 0000000,
        "persona_state": 0,
        "persona_name": "asd"
    }
]
,
"messagelast": 00,
"timestamp": 0000000000,
"utc_timestamp": 000000000000,
"messagebase": 00,
"sectimeout": 0,
"error": "OK"
})
```

And my parsing class looks like that:

```
package jsonRequest;

import java.io.IOException;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken;

public class NewMessageJson {

public Integer poollid;
private String lastMessageId;
private String error;
private String messageBase;

public NewMessageJson(String response) {
response = response.substring(response.indexOf("{"),
    response.indexOf("}") + 1); // cut off comment block


JsonFactory factory = new JsonFactory();
JsonParser jp = null;
try {
    jp = factory.createJsonParser(response);
} catch (JsonParseException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
try {

    if (jp.nextToken() != JsonToken.START_OBJECT) {
    throw new IOException("Server didn't return any data");
    }

    while (jp.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_OBJECT) {
    String fieldName = jp.getCurrentName();
    jp.nextToken();
    if (fieldName.equals("messagelast")) {
        setLastMessageId(jp.getText());
    } else if (fieldName.equals("pollid")) {
        setPoollid(jp.getIntValue());
    } else if (fieldName.equals("messagebase")) {
        setMessageBase(jp.getText());
    } else if (fieldName.equals("error")) {
        setError(jp.getText());
    }
    }
    jp.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

try {
    jp.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}

public Integer getPoollid() {
return poollid;
}

public void setPoollid(Integer poollid) {
this.poollid = poollid;
}

public String getLastMessageId() {
return lastMessageId;
}

public void setLastMessageId(String lastMessageId) {
this.lastMessageId = lastMessageId;
}

public String getError() {
return error;
}

public void setError(String error) {
this.error = error;
}

public String getMessageBase() {
return messageBase;
}

public void setMessageBase(String messageBase) {
this.messageBase = messageBase;
}

}
```

And when it comes to the line

```
if (fieldName.equals("messagelast")) {
```

It crashes and returns NPE.
I have 3 other classes looking exactly like this one and everything works perfectly.

Comment: Surely having the stack trace can't possibly help. Who reads error messages? What is the value of response after the call to substring()? Use your debugger or simply print it.

Comment: Bit of advice (may not be the issue) but instead of `fieldName.equals("messagelast")` use `"messagelast".equals(fieldName)`. This helps avoid NPEs.

Comment: @JBNizet the only error I had was NPE at line... Nothing else.

Comment: @peeskillet it works, NPE disappeared but now I got other error with "com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for ARRAY ", trying to fix

Comment: @KamilZieliński Precisely: knowing which line it is would allow us to immediately spot the problem, rather than having to guess.

Comment: @JBNizet But i typed which line throws an error "And when it comes to the line[...]"

Comment: Ok, I found out why is that returning null. It was because of my cutting comments part where i delete everything after "}" mark in multidimensional array, then it reads only first dimension, I've fixed it and works fine but thanks for your help guys, your code also works great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure the reason you are getting the NPE is because you initially instantiate `JsonParser jp` as `null`. You assign it to `factory.createJsonParser(response)` in your `try` block but do not deal with the error in any way besides printing the stack trace. If there was an error executing `factory.createJsonParser(response)`, you need to make sure nothing else runs.

I would suggest changing your code to this:

...

```
JsonFactory factory = new JsonFactory();
JsonParser jp = null;
try {
    jp = factory.createJsonParser(response);
} catch (JsonParseException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("There was an error while setting jp to factory.createJsonParser(response). Error message is: " + e1.getMessage());
} catch (IOException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("There was an error while setting jp to factory.createJsonParser(response). Error message is: " + e1.getMessage());
}

if(jp != null) {
try {

    if (jp.nextToken() != JsonToken.START_OBJECT) {
    throw new IOException("Server didn't return any data");
    }

    while (jp.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_OBJECT) {
    String fieldName = jp.getCurrentName();
    jp.nextToken();
    if (fieldName.equals("messagelast")) {
        setLastMessageId(jp.getText());
    } else if (fieldName.equals("pollid")) {
        setPoollid(jp.getIntValue());
    } else if (fieldName.equals("messagebase")) {
        setMessageBase(jp.getText());
    } else if (fieldName.equals("error")) {
        setError(jp.getText());
    }
    }
    jp.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

try {
    jp.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
```

...

This way, you can avoid all NPEs!

EDIT: You should also implement what peeskillet suggested

Comment: I've implemented what peeskillet typedand it works great. I've also  changed to what you typed, but it didn't change anything since peeskillet implemented advice. The only error i got now is "com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for ARRAY"

Comment: I actually don't have any experience with Jackson or JSON parsing. My answer was purely from a logical point of view.